# Changes to favorites are not persistent

Tags: command-line, favorites

I am using ubuntu 22.04
Changes to favorites are lost after the session ends, i.e. they are not persistent. Adding a new app to the favorite works. I can see the new favorite in dconf /org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps
However after logging out all changes are lost.

For example adding gedit as a favorite the setting /org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps is
['firefox.desktop', 'thunderbird.desktop', 'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'rhythmbox.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'snap-store_ubuntu-software.desktop', 'org.gnome.gedit.desktop']

However after logging off gedit is gone and the /org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps is again

['firefox.desktop', 'thunderbird.desktop', 'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'rhythmbox.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'snap-store_ubuntu-software.desktop']

i.e. all changes are lost

Comment: When you poweron (boot) your Ubuntu system, do you get an option to Install Ubuntu vs Try Ubuntu?

Comment: No, Ubuntu is permanently installed. Also settings like /org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/touchpad/send-events 'disabled-on-external-mouse' are preserved. Just seems to be that favorites only are lost

Comment: When you try saving a favorite, are there are any messages in your syslog or journal created by the action?

Comment: There are no entries. However I can see with dconf that the above key is correctly modified. However the login process creates a new .config/dconf/user file. Anyway stat .config/dconf/user shows that the files birth time is the last login or unlock time of the current user. As mentioned before other settings remain.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. There was a script in the startup applications resetting the favorites each time on boot. ( 'put-firefox-into-panel.sh' in my case, I don't know which process put it there ... )
Check your startup applications whether you have a similar issue.